# Automatically create bash alias when cloning git repository

Tags: git, bash, installation, alias, setup.py

I have written a piece of software MySoftware in Python that I am going to publish on GitHub and I expect some people to want to download (clone the repository) and use it. To use this software the user has to type the command `python ~/programs/MySoftware/src/main.py` or whatever the path to the `main.py` might be, which will depend on where he decides to put the Git repository.

I made an alias for this, `mysoftware='python ~/programs/MySoftware/src/main.py'`, so that when I want to use the program myself, I can just type the command `mysoftware`. I will recommend the users of my software to do the same, and most will of course do it anyway if they use the software regularly, but it would be even better if I could have this alias be created automatically on "installation", which is esentially just the process of cloning the repository.

When you f.ex. install something like `apt-get install google-chrome` the `google-chrome` alias is made automatically. That is the behaviour I want. Where are all the aliases of all our installed programs used?

I think I could make a `setup.py` or something that I would tell the user to run once in the manual and/or readme and that script could write the alias to the .bashrc. Is that a way to go? I don't really think that's what programs are doing, because I know there are no aliases in my .bashrc or .bash_aliases that I have not made myself, and it doesn't feel right to make a script that tries to write in other people's .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

`google-chrome` is not an alias. It is a binary/script installed somewhere in the user's `$PATH` variable. You could do the same with an explicit `install` step in your program's setup (assuming your program can find whatever else it needs in some standard location).

Alternatively, and I'm assuming this is the case, assuming your program requires other files from the directory it resides in then you can write a script that can operate in that matter that gets installed by the same `install` process but which uses the current directory of the repository to create the installed script on-the-fly.

That said there are quite a large number of ways this can be done but which is appropriate and how they need to be done depends largely on how your program works.